# compare values of different keys in list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries as below, I want to print url based on following conditions

if remote.value of dictionaries in list 2 = name.value of dictionaries in list 1
  myurl = fetch.value of dictionary in list 1 + name.value of dict in list 2

Has anyone done this before. with this I will get the giturl and clone the repo at revision in list 2 per dictionary

List of Dict - 1

```
[
{'fetch': 'https://github.com/cbase/', 'name': 'cbase'}, 
{'fetch': 'https://github.com/cbasela/', 'name': 'cbaselabs'} 
]
```

List if Dict - 2

```
[
{'remote': 'cbase', 'name': 'cbgt', 'revision': '06193c'}, 
{'remote': 'cbase', 'name': 'cbauth', 'revision': '1323b9'}, 
{'remote': 'cbasela', 'name': 'pink', 'revision': 'cfb33e'}
]
```

Comment: you will have to loop over the two lists and check for the condition. use list comprehension for it.

Comment: for elem1 in REMOTE:
            for elem2 in PROJ:
                if ( elem1['name'] == elem2['remote']):
                    if elem2['revision']:
                        repoList.append(elem1['fetch'] + elem2['name'] + elem2['revision'])
                    else:
                        repoList.append(elem1['fetch'] + elem2['name'])

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `list comprehension`:

```
[el1['fetch'] + el2['name'] for el1 in list1 for el2 in list2 if el1['name'] == el2['remote']]
```

output list of urls:

```
['https://github.com/cbase/cbgt', 'https://github.com/cbase/cbauth']
```

Comment: If I need to print urls and revision, I am getting key error

Comment: for elem1 in REMOTE:
            for elem2 in PROJ:
                if ( elem1['name'] == elem2['remote']):
                    if elem2['revision']:
                        repoList.append(elem1['fetch'] + elem2['name'] + elem2['revision'])
                    else:
                        repoList.append(elem1['fetch'] + elem2['name'])